# ES6 Mapping and reducing frequency count

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, es6-modules

I have a csv file that contains data in the following format (although way more data).

```
ID      COL1        COL2        COL3        COL4
-----------------------------------------------------------
1       opt1        opt1        opt1        opt1
-----------------------------------------------------------
2       opt2        opt2        opt2        opt2
-----------------------------------------------------------
3       opt3        opt3        opt3        opt3
-----------------------------------------------------------
4       opt3        opt3        opt3        opt3
-----------------------------------------------------------
5       opt3        opt3        opt3        opt3
-----------------------------------------------------------
6       opt2        opt2        opt3        opt3
-----------------------------------------------------------
7       opt4        opt2        opt2        opt2
-----------------------------------------------------------
8       opt1        opt1        opt1        opt1
-----------------------------------------------------------
9       opt2        opt5        NA          NA
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I pass this data into an array. What I am trying to do is count the frequency of values only in column one.  So at the moment, I define a list of the options

```
let labels = ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3", "opt4"];
let data = [];
```

I then have a function to count the keys

```
function countByKey (array, column, keyValue) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (array[i][column] === keyValue) {
            sum += 1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And finally a section to output the frequencies

```
for (let i in this.labels) {
    data.push({
        "Label": this.labels[i],
        "Frequency": this.countByKey(this.csv, "COL1", this.labels[i])
    });
}
```

This works fine, I end up with something like

```
[
    {
       Label: opt1
       Frequency: 42
    },
    {
       Label: opt2
       Frequency: 108
    },
    ...
]
```

However, because I am now working with ES6 within VueJS, I have seen that there are simpler ways to do this.  One way seems to be using a Map and reduce.  I have tried this

```
let acc = this.csv.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val, 1 + (acc.get(val) || 0)), new Map());
```

But that seems to output all of my data, with some sort of count.  How can I achieve the output like the above, but using ES6 features?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to use a reduce to produce an object (or Map) that counts the frequency of each label. The second step is to take this object and transform it into an array of Label / Frequency pairs that you want:

```js
const csv = [
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt1', COL2: 'opt1', COL3: 'opt1', COL4: 'opt1'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt2', COL2: 'opt2', COL3: 'opt2', COL4: 'opt2'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt3', COL2: 'opt3', COL3: 'opt3', COL4: 'opt3'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt3', COL2: 'opt3', COL3: 'opt3', COL4: 'opt3'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt3', COL2: 'opt3', COL3: 'opt3', COL4: 'opt3'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt2', COL2: 'opt2', COL3: 'opt3', COL4: 'opt3'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt4', COL2: 'opt2', COL3: 'opt2', COL4: 'opt2'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt1', COL2: 'opt1', COL3: 'opt1', COL4: 'opt1'},
  {ID: 1, COL1: 'opt2', COL2: 'opt5', COL3: 'NA', COL4: 'NA'}
]

const countByCol = col => {
  const counts = csv.reduce((memo, row) => {
    memo[row[col]] = (memo[row[col]] || 0) + 1;
    return memo;
  }, {});
  return Object.entries(counts).map(([Label, Frequency]) => ({Label, Frequency}));
};

console.log(countByCol('COL1'))
```